# How do I stop the collars on my collared shirts from twisting?

Tags: clothing, laundry

After every wash/dry, the collars on my collared shirts often start to twist in a weird way. Here’s an old shirt showing a crap ton of twisting:

[image: example of shirt with wrinkled collar]

which I haven’t been able to permanently remove fully even with an iron.

Is there any way to fix or prevent this?

Does this event have to do with the material of the shirt?

Comment: Hi rtz, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy your stay and sharing here.

Comment: Are you using a clothes dryer or do you line-dry?

Comment: @stephie I use a dryer

Answer (score 1):

Use a spray starch while you iron the collar.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably due more to the stitching if you can't flatten collars with an iron.

Try ironing the back of the collar instead of the front. Be sure you set the proper temperature for the iron.

Ironing the back of the collar also won't show a difference in the fabric on the collar to the rest of the shirt. (Sometimes ironing can make the collar fabric more shiny than the shoulder cloth which becomes evident with their close proximity to each other.)

You might even want to discuss the issue with the retailer or the (large) manufacturer's representative online.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

New dress shirts sometimes come with a curved plastic holder around the entire collar that helps it maintain a round shape. One could also put that on shirts in the closet. I can't find what this device is called, because of the much more commonly discussed collar stays.